# Sometime webdriver finds the element but sometime for the same xpath it gives nosuchelement exception

Tags: java, html, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I created a test script in which i want to click a edit button and then close the window. Most of the time the code works as expected but some time for the same code i gets nosuchelement exception. I went through the similar questions asked in the forum but none of the solution worked for me. Below i am putting the java code along with the HTML Code in hope to find a solution.

```
for(String newwindow : window.getWindowHandles()){
//swithching to the new pop up using window.switchTo().window(passing newwindow as argument)    
window.switchTo().window(newwindow);}
//getting title of new window using getTitle() method
System.out.println("NewWindow Title"+ window.getTitle());
window.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='edit_resume_section3_open' and not(@disabled)]")).click();
window.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
System.out.println(window.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='title']")).getAttribute("value"));
window.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
window.findElement(By.id("update")).click();
window.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
window.close();

Html Code for the webelement-
 <head>
 <body class="bg_lightgreen" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" onload="" leftmargin="0"    topmargin="0" style="">
 <iframe id="_yuiResizeMonitor" style="position: absolute; visibility: visible; width: 10em; height: 10em; top: -120px; left: -120px; border-width: 0px;"/>
 <div id="fade_nation_mismatch" class="black_overlay"/>
 <div id="fade_visual_resume" class="black_overlay"/>
 <div id="show_visual_resume" class="white_content" style="position: absolute; top: 25%;">
 <table class="bg_purple" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
 <table class="bg_white" width="998" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="20" border="0" align="center">
 <table class="bg_white" width="998" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="20" border="0" align="center">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="font_15 txt_purple bold" width="203" style="padding-bottom:5px; width:250px; word-wrap: break-word;">1.6YR Experiance/BSC(CS)</td>
<td width="715" style="padding-bottom:5px;">
<a id="edit_resume_section3_open" class="thickbox" title="Professional Details"  style="cursor:pointer" onclick="showEditSection(3);">[Edit]</a>
</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

First ensure your xpath expression (or whatever you use to find the element) is correct in any case. For element dynamicaly generated, your xpath expression could not be valid in any case.

If it is correct, it means you get race condition. The element you're looking for is sometime not ***yet*** present. It might depend on your browser that could take more time to render the page at that time, or the http server that might take more time to serve your page. There could be many (stupid) reasons.

In order to fix it you have to use pooling. Check the presence of your element. If present, proceed. If not present, wait and try again. The class 'com.thoughtworks.selenium.Wait' fit that purpose.

You will find example using 'com.thoughtworks.selenium.Wait example' as keyword in google.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking if the element is present in a loop before trying to click on it

Comment: The element is present in the loop and sometime webdriver finds it and sometime it fails to find the same element

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use ID for finding the element. Since it has an ID, you can use that. While doing automation using xpath is not that preferable if you have other options. xpath may change.
I think the below line is used for opening the link,

```
window.findElement(By.id("edit_resume_section3_open")).click();
```

Also, there is no need to use implicit  waits before every line. Once you declared, it will be affected for all lines in your test.
If you want to use wait for every line, then try explicit waits.